# href refer to link with file-protocol

Tags: html, file, protocols, href

I would refer to a link on a intern file-server which have an html file.
My Code looks like this:

```
<a href="file://///192.168.115.203/fileserver/v_collection/search.html" target="_blank">
 <table class="linkTable">
  <tr class="linkTableLine">
   <td class="linkTxtCell">Icon Experience V-Collection</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</a>
```

The server is reachable in our intern network and if i copy the link and insert it in the browser-bar it works.
But if i click the button in my HTML-File it do nothing. I try it in Chrome, Mozilla and in in IE.
After search I found some old threads, that come to the end, that the browser wouldn´t open local files because of security guidelines.
But in my way it is only show a html file from a other server. The HTML-File can´t be copy to the html-server because there a much more files to search in it.

Can i fix my problem or is it unfixable ?

Edit:
I try to test the code and it works. But in my php-created site it wont work. I will give you the whole table:

```
<table class="links" cellspacing="5px">
<tr>
<td class="link">
<a href="file://///192.168.115.203/fileserver/Icons/IconExperience/v_collection/search.html" target="_blank"><table class="linkTable">
<tr class="linkTableLine">
<td class="linkTxtCell">
Icon Experience V-Collection
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and the css:

```
.link {
    font-weight: normal;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #303030;
    max-height: 23px;
    background: #e2e2e2; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e2e2e2 0%, #dbdbdb 50%, #d1d1d1 51%, #fefefe
        100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #e2e2e2),
        color-stop(50%, #dbdbdb), color-stop(51%, #d1d1d1),
        color-stop(100%, #fefefe) ); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e2e2e2 0%, #dbdbdb 50%, #d1d1d1 51%,
        #fefefe 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e2e2e2 0%, #dbdbdb 50%, #d1d1d1 51%, #fefefe
        100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e2e2e2 0%, #dbdbdb 50%, #d1d1d1 51%, #fefefe
        100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e2e2e2 0%, #dbdbdb 50%, #d1d1d1 51%, #fefefe
        100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(              startColorstr='#e2e2e2',
        endColorstr='#fefefe', GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.link:hover {
    background: rgb(230, 240, 163); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 240, 163, 1) 0%,
        rgba(210, 230, 56, 1) 50%, rgba(195, 216, 37, 1) 51%,
        rgba(219, 240, 67, 1) 100% ); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(230,
        240, 163, 1) ), color-stop(50%, rgba(210, 230, 56, 1) ),
        color-stop(51%, rgba(195, 216, 37, 1) ),
        color-stop(100%, rgba(219, 240, 67, 1) ) ); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 240, 163, 1) 0%,
        rgba(210, 230, 56, 1) 50%, rgba(195, 216, 37, 1) 51%,
        rgba(219, 240, 67, 1) 100% ); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 240, 163, 1) 0%,
        rgba(210, 230, 56, 1) 50%, rgba(195, 216, 37, 1) 51%,
        rgba(219, 240, 67, 1) 100% ); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 240, 163, 1) 0%,
        rgba(210, 230, 56, 1) 50%, rgba(195, 216, 37, 1) 51%,
        rgba(219, 240, 67, 1) 100% ); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(230, 240, 163, 1) 0%,
        rgba(210, 230, 56, 1) 50%, rgba(195, 216, 37, 1) 51%,
        rgba(219, 240, 67, 1) 100% ); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(                 
        startColorstr='#e6f0a3', endColorstr='#dbf043', GradientType=0 );
    /* IE6-9 */
}

table.linkTable {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use 'http://'?

Comment: I try it to make a testfile and it works. With this code in top. My html-site was created in php.

Comment: because the file is not in a webserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible because of browser security settings.